# Will Specifying Multiple Remotes Mean That Code is Pushed To All Remote Repos?

Tags: git

If I have a repo that has multiple remotes specified, does that mean when I do a git push then the code is pushed to all the remotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Slightly longer answer: you can `git fetch` from more than one remote, using `git fetch --all`<sup>1</sup> or `git remote update`, but you can only push to one remote at a time.  The remote chosen is that given on the command line:

```
git push $remote $refspec_list
```

If you omit `$refspec_list` you can omit `$remote` as well, and in this case, the remote that is chosen is the (single) remote based on where the *current branch* should be pushed by default.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that `git fetch` fetches based on the refspec arguments or configured refspec(s), but normally only fetches from one remote too.  Adding `--all` has no effect on the set of refspecs: it just means that `git fetch` should loop through all defined remotes.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you simply add remote by `git remote add remote_name remote_url`
However it's possible if you want to push to multi remotes at the same time, you can check  [pull/push from multiple remote locations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3195446/13338936) for detail info